# Overflow & border-radius : PIE not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I can't get `border-radius` property work on IE8, even with PIE.

#### What I am trying to do ?

A progress bar

#### HOW ?

A parent div with round border (`border-radius: 15px`) and a grey background. A child div (rectangular) with green background. The child corners should be hidden outside of the parent shape (`overflow:hidden`).

#### Problem :

On IE8, the parent shape has round corners but the child div has not (You can get the same result on other browser by removing `overflow: hidden`)

#### Why this solution "[Overflow:hidden for rounded borders using css3pie in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765434/overflowhidden-for-rounded-borders-using-css3pie-in-ie8)" does not answer my problem ?

I don't want my child div to have round corners, for instance at 61% ([see my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvx9P/)), the right side of the green shape is rectangular. (I don't want to add `border-radius` property on it)

#### Code & Demo ?

JSFiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvx9P/)

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress" style="width:61%"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    background: #AAA;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(/Content/PIE.htc);
    /* REMOVE TO SEE THE RESULT ON IE8 : */
    overflow:hidden;
}

.progress {
    height: 100%;
    background: #5F5;
}
```

Does anyone has an idea to deal with it ?

Comment: You shouldn't bother. It's far easier and it's going to be better (cleaner and more performant) to simply have a square progress bar in IE8 and below

Comment: Well, for now it is the fallback, but for some people (whose problem is not a progress bar) it could be a blocking problem. I will leave this question open and hope someone will find a workaround.